# Particle と in "Feliksas と申します。"

Tags: grammar, particle-と

This phrase is used pretty much on every intro page to Japan, as a polite way to state "my name is _____". I think it's similar to *Je m'appelle*. My question is why is it exactly the particle と used in this case? Is it a unique thing, or is there a bigger trend? Is it used as a quotative way -- "Feliksas (quote - as in quoting what people say) am called"?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: It's similar to _je m'appelle_ in that it means "my name is", but I hope you don't think that the French reflexive _me = m'_ has anything to do with the Japanese particle と.

Comment: No, I don't. My wonder is why in this situation particle と is used :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you are right, the と is used as a quote. Feliksas - I am called that.

Once you know the root of the word 申します the reason becomes clear.
申します is the keigo (polite) form of 言います.

と言います　can be used for reported speech.

あの女の子は「私はもう大丈夫です」と言いました。

That girl said "I am all right now".

That girl said she was all right at the time.

On a side note - if you are writing Japanese try to avoid romaji, even in names like Feliksas since most Japanese won't know how to pronounce it.